# Setting up nginx as proxy to apache; All good, but nginx doesn't serve media

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, nginx

I have set it up such that nginx proxies request and sends django requests to apache and serves media itself.

Following documents my setup:

Nginx Configuration: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}

=====
```

ngnix proxy `/etc/nginx/proxy.conf`

```
============
proxy_redirect              off;
proxy_set_header            Host $host;
proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size        10m;
client_body_buffer_size     128k;
proxy_connect_timeout       90;
proxy_send_timeout          90;
proxy_read_timeout          90;
proxy_buffer_size           4k;
proxy_buffers               4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
===========
```

Nginx server file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/some-name.txt

```
==========
server {

    listen 208.109.252.110:80;
    server_name netconf;

    autoindex on;


    access_log /home/site/server_logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/site/server_logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }

    location /site_media/ {
        root /home/site/folder/static;
    }

 }

==========
```

Nginx very well proxies the request and passes to apache, the required requests, but doesn't serve the media. In the last server file, location site_media is not served, at all. :(

Everything seems perfect to me. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my method work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|ico|swf)$ {
  root /home/site/folder/static;
  expires 7d;
```

You will then have the files with those extension delivered from a different place. You can give then different expire dates and compression etc also.

The complete file would look like this:

```
server {

    listen 208.109.252.110:80;
    server_name netconf;

    autoindex on;


    access_log /home/site/server_logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/site/server_logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }

    location location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|ico|swf)$ {
        root /home/site/folder/static;
        expires 7d;
    }
}
```

You might also want to add some more options to your files. Check out the following links for some special options for dynamic and static content and some overall security issues.

- [Nginx "how to" - Fast and Secure Web Server](https://calomel.org/nginx.html)
- [Top 20 Nginx WebServer Best Security Practices](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html)